# Serverside OAuth Login

Tags: java, oauth, client-server

I am getting confused.

I have to write an Java Serverapplication for an mobile application. We have our own user management in that application, meaning the user can register and login on our servers without using an OAuth-Provider at all.

Now I want the user to be able to alternativly register via an OAuth Provider.

These are the options I see:

**Let the user register local only.**

Advantage:

- The mobile applications can use the frameworks which are able to login and retrieve an access token for our application
- Everything is prestyled by the platform itself, so no GUI work on that

Disadvantage:

- How does the server know if the user is logged in or not? One way to figure that out could be to send the access token to the server and let the server start a request to the provider to check if the token is valid or not.
- For the registration I have to send all user information which the client got from the provider to our servers.

I dont like this option, cause I would send Userdata and Accesstoken arround. Yes, it would be crypted via https of course, but it just feels wrong.

**Let the user register via our servers**

The user requests the OAuth provider itself to retreive the code with which you could request the access token.
Send this code to the server and let the server retreive the acess token.

Advantage:

- The Server can be sure now, that the user is logged in
- The server can retreive all user specific information about the user (such as username etc) from the OAuth provider itself, without sending the arround.
- On a login you can repeat this, to make sure that the user is logged in correctly

Disadvantage:

- I have to write the OAuth connectors (or using some library for that)
- We are not able to use the sdk's, cause they're just returning the actual access token.

We still prefer the first option (register local only)
Because

- they WANT to use the sdks. "'cause everyone does it."
- If the user would start the application the first time and he was logged in already (with i.e. the FB client), he just has to accept the scopes, we setted up for our application.
- Easier to handle the actual login, cause the sdk's where made for it

Does anyone know how to do something like that correctly? Both solutions seem a bit wrong to me.